# Getting first string from a web address

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

I am trying to get a name from a list of websites and need only the first string or word to be more precise. I have found a way in Python but I am interested in doing it with PostgreSQL

For example I would need happy from `https://www.happy.com`.

I used following code but I think I am going in a wrong direction:

```sql
WITH test AS (SELECT regexp_replace('https://www.happy.com','(https://www.|https://|http://)',''))
SELECT SPLIT_PART(test,'.',0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('https://www.happy.com',
                      '^(?:(?:ht|f)tps?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)(.*)\.[^.]+$',
                      '\1') AS Result;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DAI84C/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:ht|f)tps?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)` - `http://www.`, `https://www.`, `ftp://www.`, `ftps://www.`, `https://`, `http://`, `ftps://`, `ftp://` or just `www.`
- `(.*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `[^.]+` - one or more chars other than a `.` char
- `$` - end of string.